# GET SCIM GROUPS only returns synthetic_group in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scim

I am trying to list all the SCIM groups in snowflake but I only get `synthetic_group`

```
{
  "schemas" : [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse" ],
  "Resources" : [ {
    "schemas" : [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group" ],
    "id" : "1",
    "meta" : {
      "resourceType" : "Group",
      "created" : "2021-12-29T09:11:10Z",
      "lastModified" : "2021-12-29T09:11:10Z"
    },
    "displayName" : "synthetic_group",
    "members" : [ ]
  } ],
  "totalResults" : 1,
  "startIndex" : 1,
  "itemsPerPage" : 1
```

I don't know whether it is some problem with privileges or something else. I am using the following curl.

```
curl -i -X GET  -H "Authorization:Bearer <bearer-token>"       'https://<account_name>.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com/scim/v2/Groups'
```

I have created the integration using the queries given in [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-custom.html#create-a-custom-scim-security-integration-and-api-token).

```
use role accountadmin;
create role if not exists generic_scim_provisioner;
grant create user on account to role generic_scim_provisioner;
grant create role on account to role generic_scim_provisioner;
grant role generic_scim_provisioner to role accountadmin;
create or replace security integration generic_scim_provisioning
    type=scim
    scim_client='generic'
    run_as_role='GENERIC_SCIM_PROVISIONER';
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to list all groups in Snowflake. As far as know, it has been already requested functionality on the roadmap.

For more details on the timeline, please raise a Snowflake support case.

Available SCIM API Requests: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5462540/S1Lzx6gY?version=latest#3b1f8e3c-ea80-4840-a81a-118bf22fdc42